# Joining 3 tables to get different attributes

Tags: oracle

I have staff, department ,location tables.

I want to display staff name,department name,city name from these 3 tables.
can someone help me i am new to oracle.

Comment: Do you know how to join 2 tables?  What are your table definitions?  What keys relate these tables together?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: www.google.com?q=sql+tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Simple example:

```
select 
s.person_name, 
d.department_name, 
l.city_name
from staff s 
JOIN department d
ON s.something = d.something
JOIN location l
ON l.something = d.something
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT s.first_name, d.department_name, l.city
    FROM staff s, department d, locations l
    WHERE s.depart_id = d.depart_id
    AND d.location_id = l.location_id;
```

Comment: This solution assumes that location is associated with the department as opposed to the staff.  What if John and Mary both DBAs in the IT department work as a teleworkers from New York and Sacramento respectively?